# Null reference in infragistics active row of the grid

Tags: grid, infragistics

I am using Infragistics grid control. Why the following code throwing null reference exception.

```
foreach (UltraGridRow row in grdDemo.Rows)
{
DemoList objDemoList = row.ListObject as DemoList; 
}
```

The following line found in google but i am not getting when and why will get this exception. 
**Returns the object corresponding to this row from the IList that the control is bound to. Returns Null if this is an UltraGridGroupByRow.**

Comment: The code above should not trigger a null reference exception unless (in a subsequent line) you use the `objDemoList` variable without checking for null. Could you show how and where you use the `objDemoList` variable?

Comment: What Steve said is accurate unless the exception is thrown for another reason like improper use of threading.  Can you also post the full exception detail with the call stack?